# Asterisk/chan_dongle: Receiving Concatenated SMS

Tags: php, sms, asterisk

I'm using Asterisk with chan_dongle (and Huawei UMTS stick) on Debian Wheezy. I can send and receive SMS successfully. The 7-bit de/encoding work is done by a simple PHP script.

My problem is, that I can't receive concatenated SMS. This is the Base64 text from two different messages:

```
Ym9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVX
WHNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVtBYm9LZWl1a1NfYUNnSU1PUVVXWXNxR21FXVs=

CENdV0tBTH1lQUhLU11LQShLU1ldQ1FbS0FCXUFIS2VBYENzZ0NNS0dDZUlbAldpU19dXUAIS1NdS0FgS2VneV1ZU0dRS0FgQ3NnQ01LR0NlSUEEX11rZ0EgEx1BUGpACislU0BYQ2tpS2l1QEBgcGBsQGxyaHJAaHJiYkBubGBkdkAmS2VTS11da1tbS2V1cmJiZmxsbmxo
XEAOfVlpU09BRFNnQWZiXGBwXGRgYmhcAA==
```

The first one is a simple repeating "qwertz..." dummy text, sent from my Android phone.
The second one is a (German) reply from a service provider with a coupon code.

The first one looks easy to decode. 7/8 bit magic and we're done.
But the second one is really strange. Any ideas how to decode it?

Answer (score 0):

There is only way to deal with multipart SMS is working as PDU with it and concatenating in your application.

Comment: Looks like a bug in chan_dongle or a wrong format by the the sender. Because I can receive other multipart SMS  without any problems.